# Best way to create a responsive prototype?

Tags: design, responsive-design, prototype, testing

Are there any platforms or tools to create a responsive prototype?

Answer (score 2):

Actually most modern wireframing tools offer this option (in different ways).

### Figma

[Using constraints & “magic numbers” to build responsive layouts in Figma](https://www.figma.com/blog/creating-responsive-layout-templates-in-figma/)

> Figma is great for building with responsive constraints — you can stretch your layouts and see how they will respond to changes in screen size. (If you’re new to constraints in Figma, [check out this beginner primer here](http://check%20out%20this%20beginner%20primer%20here.).)

[image]

### Axure

[Adaptive Views](https://docs.axure.com/axure-rp/pages/adaptive-views/) - in Axure you basically just create different screens that trigger at certain breakpoints.

> Adaptive views are alternate versions of pages designed for specific screen sizes. They allow you to create a page once and then rearrange, resize, and restyle its widgets to fit each screen size you intend to test it on.
>   When you view the page in a web browser, the appropriate view for the browser dimensions will be shown automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adobe XD has some responsive features now that might help your design along. Here is the intro video from Adobe that will give you some insight: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKvg8_8jv10